# stop at a/the red light

Tags: articles

1 The car went through the red light. (I think only THE is possible)

2 The car stopped at the red light. (I wonder whether there are any contexts in which A would work? Or would it take not a specific car for that? Cars stop at a red light)

Comment: Cars go THROUGH red lights rather than AT them.

Answer (score 2):

*A red light* would be appropriate if you are referring to one of many sets of traffic lights which the car passed on its journey.

> Half an hour later, the car had stopped at a red light when...

*The red light* - a particular one.

> At the junction with X Street, the car had stopped at the red light.

Comment: If it's a generally true situation. Cars should stop at a red light OR the red light.

Comment: At **a** red light, since it doesn't refer to a particular one.

Comment: The rose is my favorite flower. It's "the rose" which encompasses all the roses in the world. Why can't we use "the red light" the same way? Cars should stop at the red light.